# python threads - run with timeout

Tags: python, multithreading, synchronization

We have created a pool of workers to crawl web pages in background with the similar to the one below

```
import requests 
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

urls = [
  ...
  ]

# Make the Pool of workers
pool = ThreadPool(4) 
results = pool.map(requests.get, urls)
pool.close() 
pool.join()
```

**Question:**

The system hangs sometimes. 
Observed for some cases the get method is not returning and hence the whole system hangs.

What I am looking for?
Is there a way to set timeout for thread execution and close the thread to return empty?

Comment: No, not in general.  You'd need processes instead of threads for this.  Processes can be killed from the outside (via signals).  Single threads of a process only can terminate from the inside (they have to do it themselves).  You might be able to program the threads in a way so that they terminate on a timeout, e. g. a network timeout.

Comment: In the specific case of `requests.get`, you could provide a value for the [`timeout`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts) argument.

Comment: @kevin we currently have implemented with the timeout in requests.get method. wondering any control @ the thread level